# Writing a vector to 3rd dimension of a 3D array in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I am working on a multi-band Raster image. For the processing Raster is converted to matrix and then pixel wise processed. I am facing problem in **writing the pixel values to the blank 3d array** which is explained below.

let us assume

I have a blank `3D array`

```
x = array(0,c(4,5,3))
x
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

and a `vector`

```
y = c(5,14)
```

I want to copy values of `y` in the `3rd dimension of x` so that output look like example given below

```
x
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    14    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    NA    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I have searched on the internet but I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: `x[1,1,] <- c(y, NA)` will do it.